# Set site icon on android chrome main screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I try to set icon for site on bookmark panel in Chrome Android such as:
[image: screenshot]

By default, it outputs first letter of site name as picture.

How to add custom icon to site to show on this screen?

Simple adding android icons doesn't work. Opengraph markup (og:image) doesn't work too.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/logo/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/logo/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/logo/icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/logo/icons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/logo/icons/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
```

What should I add to page to set this icon?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/browser-customization/

Comment: Try to set `manifest.json` in your site's `head` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)